# using FISH shell -- set default folder for multiple tabs?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal.app, fish

I'm using [fish](http://fishshell.com) shell in OS X. Using the standard bash shell, you can open multiple tabs in Terminal, `cd` to a different directory in each, and then save the setup as a Window Group (via `Window > Save As Window Group`); doing so will re-open those same tabs and those same default directories every time you start up Terminal.

Doing this in fish, however, doesn't seem to work -- saving the window group doesn't take. Is there a way to have fish save the current directory in each tab and persist across Terminal launches?

(Note: duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/195939/74519 -- I'll delete whichever one doesn't get an answer).

Comment: You might want to ask on https://apple.stackexchange.com/ -- this is not a question about bash or fish, it's about how Terminal saves the state of the shell sessions.

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman I'll swap the question over there if I don't get an answer here. Since it's more on the technical side of things, SU is still legit.